# Merge one git repo in subdirectory of another one while keeping history without using --follow

Tags: git, git-filter-repo

I am currently cleaning up some git repos. Current status:

> repo_A->Content_A

> repo_B->Content_B

The new planned status is to have a clean repo, with A and B (names different from the original repos) as subdirs and in these subdirs the original content:

> new_repo->A->Content_A

> new_repo->B->Content_B

I want to keep the history on all the files Content_A and Content_B and as other software is accessing the history, using the --follow while using the log command is not really an option.

So far I tried a lot of things, subtree and submodules is not really fitting my use case either. The most promising solution I found and followed was given in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10548919

I also included the added points for the subdir part, but in the end, I end up with all the files of repo_A not in new_repo->A-> but still in new_repo->. Moving the files in a subdir then loses the history (without using --follow). I will give you my workflow, that is adapted from the answer mentioned above. I work in the Windows PowerShell, all repos are freshly cloned in the local directories.

```
cd path\to\dir\that\contains\all\the\repos
cd .\repo_A\
git filter-repo --to-subdirectory-filter A
cd ..\new_repo\
git remote add A ..\repo_A\
git fetch A --tags
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories A/master
git remote remove A
```

The comments to the mentioned answer and als the cited merge of Rubygems and Bundler seem to end up in a subdirectory, but my files end up directly in \new_repo\ and not in \new_repo\A\ (at least the history is fine). Only big difference in comparison to the Rubygems/Bundler-Merge-Output.txt is, that in my case, the filter-repo has no output at all, it starts and stops after one second without feedback.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are on the right track!

All you need to do is install `git filter-repo`. it is not part of git, you have to install it separately.
Link for repo incase you want to install manually - https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo)

Install command for Debian linux,

```
sudo apt install git-filter-repo
```

Install command for mac,

```
brew install git-filter-repo
```

------ update from submitter ------

In the git filter-repo code, the top line (shebang) was set to  `#!/usr/bin/env python3`. My windows environment only recognise `python` and not `python3`.

Two option to fix:

Option 1: Changing the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/env python` in filter-repo code.

Option 2: creating a link to python3 in windows. Please refer this post, many options discussed -> https://superuser.com/questions/1576758/how-do-i-alias-python3-on-windows

---

Example:

I tested it after installing `git-filter-repo`. It works like charm!

sample output:

```
project-a % git filter-repo --to-subdirectory-filter project-a
Parsed xxx commits
New history written in 0.08 seconds; now repacking/cleaning...
Repacking your repo and cleaning out old unneeded objects
Updating files: 100% (1052/1052), done.
HEAD is now at d675bxxx 55xx 7 modification to add validations for all scenarios
Enumerating objects: 1952, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1952/1952), done.
Delta compression using up to 10 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (668/668), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1952/1952), done.
Total 1952 (delta 904), reused 1952 (delta 904), pack-reused 0
Completely finished after 1.60 seconds.

project-a  %
```

Comment: @buecki was it helpful?

Comment: Indeed the git filter-repo itself was the problem, but not the installation as you described, but actually in the git filter-repo code, the top line was set to "python3" instead of "python", and so it simply never exectued, as the python in windows was only rechable as "python". Can you add this to your answer? As your explanation is very thorough and might help others if this "python3" is also included, I will then choose as the solution.