# move git repo to another repo's subdirectory while preserving commit history

Tags: git, commit, subdirectory

move git repo to another repo's **subdirectory** while preserving commit history. Say, I have a git named old_repo, I hope to move it to new_repo/sub_dir_4_old_repo.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a perfect job for [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Basically, you'd start a new project from scratch, then reference the old repo as a path.

```bash
git init
git submodule add https://example.com/myuser/oldrepo.git sub_dir_4_old_repo
git commit -m 'Initial commit - add old repo as submodule'
```

The two repositories would have a separate history, but you can [in the new project] check in changes to the submodule's pointer periodically.

If you're starting with an existing repo, say hosted on codeberg.org, the steps would be slightly different:

```bash
git clone https://codeberg.org/h3xx/perl-Chicken-Ipsum
git submodule add https://example.com/myuser/oldrepo.git sub_dir_4_old_repo
git commit -m 'Initial commit - add old repo as submodule'
```

The new and repos do NOT have to be on the same server.

[TMTOWTDI](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/TMTOWTDI), so this isn't the end-all be-all of solutions. Other options include:

- Keep the same repo and just move all the old files to the subdirectory. I.e. `mkdir sub_dir_4_old_repo && git mv * sub_dir_4_old_repo && git commit`
- Simply leave the old versions out on an unmerged branch and start over. I.e. `git checkout -b starting-over && git rm -rf * && git commit -m 'Starting over'`
- Rewrite the entire old repo's history to all take place within `/sub_dir_4_old_repo` instead of `/` (not recommended). I.e. Use `git rebase -i --root` and edit *every single commit* to instead of making its changes to `/path/foo.txt` make its changes to `/sub_dir_4_old_repo/path/foo.txt`. This is a **lot** of work and can lead to all sorts of problems unless everyone re-clones your repo.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use submodule and merge those repo, follow this (git filter repo to the rescue)

[How do you merge two Git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories/10548919#10548919)

Some nuances fixed,

[Merge one git repo in subdirectory of another one while keeping history without using --follow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77493063/merge-one-git-repo-in-subdirectory-of-another-one-while-keeping-history-without)